# Adding a file download link to a node

Tags: 8, nodes, files

I have a content type `recipe` and for each recipe type content I want to add a link which can download the recipe for the user.

How can this be done in Drupal 8.5.2?

I'm not sure if I should provide a field to attach the file or if it should be done in some other way like creating a template adding the values to it dynamically and then generating a PDF for the template and attaching a download link for it.

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate more how you have set it up right now? Do you have a field for the upload attached to the node?

Comment: this is what im actually not sure about if i should provide a field to attach the file or if it should be done in some other way like creating a template adding the values to it dynamically and then generating a pdf for the template and attaching a download link for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds that you should be able to implement what you want like so:

- Add a custom field to your `recipe`, assume you use a machine name like "`file-containing-recipe`" (change this name to whatever fits).
- For the `file-containing-recipe` field, specify a field type "*file*", and combine it with whatever other configuration options that fit (eg: single value or multiple values, optional or mandatory, etc).

To verify your configuration, create a node of content type `recipe`, and use the newly defined "`file-containing-recipe`"-field to actually attach your file(s). After saving the new node, verify if the results are what you're asking for. If (still) not, go back to your "`file-containing-recipe`"-configuration to further tune any of its settings.

***Done***.